# List the files in a directory based on a list of names provided by user in java

Tags: java, file

Currently, I am able to obtain the list of names of files using the following function.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List < String > s = new ArrayList < > ();
        s.add("AulaIternational.pdf");
        s.add("Spanish Essentials For Dummies.pdf");
        List < File > flist = new ArrayList < > ();

        for (String str: s) {
            File newFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Spanish Training\\" + str);
            if (newFile.exists()) {
                flist.add(newFile);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(flist);
    }
}
```

Output : "C:\Users\Spanish Training\AulaIternational.pdf, C:\Users\Spanish Training\Spanish Essentials For Dummies.pdf"

My Question: **Can the same thing be simplified using file.listfile(Filter) or I am doing the correct thing?**

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the old cumbersome file io library instead of NIO?

Comment: Modern stream variant: `Path base = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Spanish Training");` and then `List<Path> files = List.of("foo.pdf", "bar.pdf").forEach(base::resolve).filter(Files::exists).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Thats it.

Comment: Yes I have to perform this on AS400 server and nio is not working on it

Comment: @Zabuzard - Thanks mate, but this List.of("abc.pdf") won't work [The method of(String) is undefined for the type List]

Comment: The method is from Java 9. Then you are on an older version. You can still create the list by any other means, like `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

Will not simplify too much, but looks bit more readable

```
List<File> flist = Arrays.asList(new File("C:\\Users\\Spanish Training\\").listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return s.contains(name);
}}));
```